# Store permanently an information

Tags: installation, storage, internals, permanent, credits

fisrt sorry for my english...

How is it possible to know if an user has installed the application for the first time ? I explain my need : when the user install my application, he has for example 10 credits for free. But after, if he needs more credits he has to paid... My problem is that if he deletes the application and he install again, he has 10 credits for free... How to store the number of credits permanently ?

I already try to use sharepreference, but data are deleted if I clear the application

thank you

gigi

Answer (score 0):

you can use sessions and cookies and write than , if cookie close, delete credit card or another logic.

Comment: a cookie is persistent ? and the user is able to delete the cookie ?

Comment: not cookie is not persistent, you can set time when delete it automatically, it's so useful tool. for example: when user delete application delete cookie and e.t.c

Comment: OK thank, so this logic doesn't answer to my need

Comment: sorry if this is unuseful

Comment: which language do you use can you answer me?

Comment: Java on android

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.